# Laravel error must be of the type array, string given, called in

Tags: laravel

**ERROR**

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
>   Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in mypath\app\Http\Controllers\PostsController.php on line 65

**Controller**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
       {


    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' =>  'required',
        'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'body'  =>  'required'
    ]);

    //dd($request); 

    auth()->user()->publish(
        Storage::putFile('images', new File($request['image']), 'public'),
        new Post(request('title', 'image', 'body'))

    );

    session()->flash('message', 'your post has now been published');

    return redirect('/');        

}
```

......

Comment: in error message you have simple solution. Bad type of data!

Answer (score 4):

You need to give request parameters to create new post in array format like this,

```
$request->only('title', 'image', 'body')
```

So that your code looks like,

```
auth()->user()->publish(
    Storage::putFile('images', new File($request['image']), 'public'),
    Post::create($request->only('title', 'image', 'body')))

);
```

I hope you will understand.